# Robot moving in a grid

Tags: algorithm

A robot is located at the top-left corner of a 4x4 grid. 
The robot can move either up, down, left, or right, but can not visit the same spot twice.
The robot is trying to reach the bottom-right corner of the grid.The number of ways it can reach the bottom-right corner of the grid is?

Now i know that if the robot can only move down or right ,then the answer would be 8C4 because it has to go 4 squares to the right and 4 squares down, in any order.

But i am having difficulty in solving the problem when the robot can move both left and up!?

I just need a hint to solve the problem! How should i approach the problem?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-avoiding_walk

Comment: With a 2x2, there are only two paths. What about a 3x3?

Comment: "Now i know that if the robot can only move down or right ,then the answer would be 8C4 because it has to go 4 squares to the right and 4 squares down, in any order." I don't get it, if the robot can only go right and down, it still has plenty of different ways of going  to the bottom right corner, hasen't it?

Comment: @user2227862 It will take more than half an hour to write it, but it should be feasible. I'll try it tonight (EU here)

Comment: http://oeis.org/A007764

Comment: So the answer is 184. thanks @MarkusJarderot

Comment: From @Alex's link:  *"There is currently no known formula for determining the number of self-avoiding walks, although there are rigorous methods for approximating them.  Finding the number of such paths is conjectured to be an NP-hard problem"*  - So, your only option is brute-force (or hard-code the sequence from Markus's link, if your grid is square).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a recursive program that calculates all possible paths, and whenever it arrives at the down right corner it increments the number of paths. I wrote something, but I didn't test it. (Think of it as pseudocode to give you a start). Basically what this does, is call the moveRobot function on the current position (0, 0) with an empty field (the robot hasn't moved yet). Then it tries to move up, down, left and right. This movement is described in the respective functions. If one of these movements succeds(or more than one), the new position is marked in the field with a 1 instead of a 0. 1 means the robot has passed through that position. Then you call moveRobot again. This because in the new position you want to try all four movements once more.

Main Function:

```
int field[4][4];
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        field[i][j] = 0;
field[0][0] = 1;
numPaths = 0;
moveRobot(0, 0, field);
print numPaths;
```

MoveRobot Function:

```
moveRobot(int row, int column, int[][] field)
{
    moveRobotUp(row, column, field);
    moveRobotDown(row, column, field);
    moveRobotLeft(row, column, field);
    moveRobotRight(row, column, field);
}
```

Other Functions:

```
moveRobotUp(int row, int column, int[][] field)
{
    if (row == 0) return;
    else 
    {
        if (field[row-1][column] == 1) return;
        field[row-1][column] = 1;
        moveRobot(row-1, column, field);
        field[row-1][column] = 0;
    }
}

moveRobotDown(int row, int column, int[][] field)
{
    if (row == 3 && column == 3) 
    {
        numPaths++;
        return;
    }
    else if (row == 3) return;
    else
    {
        if (field[row+1][column] == 1) return;
        field[row+1][column] = 1;
        moveRobot(row+1, column, field);
        field[row+1][column] = 0;
    }
}

moveRobotLeft(int row, int column, int[][] field)
{
    if (column == 0) return;
    else
    {
        if (field[row][column-1] == 1) return;
        field[row][column-1] = 1;
        moveRobot(row, column-1, field);
        field[row][column-1] = 0;
    }
}

moveRobotRight(int row, int column, int[][] field)
{
    if (column == 3 && row == 3) 
    {
        numPaths++;
        return;
    }
    else if (column == 3) return;
    else 
    {
        if (field[row][column+1] == 1) return;
        field[row][column+1] = 1;
        moveRobot(row, column+1, field);
        field[row][column+1] = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to reset the cell to zero on back-track. Also, instead of five separate functions only a generalized one is enough, with moving described as coordinate offset (±1,0),(0,±1).

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I tried to do as you say about resetting the cell. Do you think I did it right? I am not very good in recursion...  If there's more to edit, feel free to do it :)

Answer (score 3):

This will work fine. The answer is 184.

```
public class RobotMovementProblem 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int grid[][]=new int[4][4];
        System.out.println(countPaths(grid, 0, 0));
    }
    static int countPaths(int grid[][],int i,int j)
    {

        if ( i < 0 || j < 0 || i >= 4 || j >= 4 ) return 0;
        if ( grid[i][j] == 1 ) return 0;
        if ( i == 3 && j == 3 ) return 1;
        int arr[][]=new int[4][4];
        for(int m=0;m<4;m++)
        {
            for(int n=0;n<4;n++)
            {
                arr[m][n]=grid[m][n];
            }
        }

        arr[i][j] = 1;
        return countPaths(arr, i, j+1) + countPaths(arr, i, j-1) +  countPaths(arr, i+1, j) + countPaths(arr, i-1, j);  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/* building on red_eyes answer */

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main m = new Main();
    boolean grid [][]= new boolean [4][4];
    sol=0;
    grid[0][0]= true;
    m.start(0,1,grid);
    System.out.println(sol);//output 184
}

    private void start(int x, int y,boolean [][]grid){
    grid[x][y]=true;
    moveUp(x,y,grid);
    moveDown(x,y,grid);     
    moveLeft(x,y,grid);     
    moveRight(x,y,grid);         
}

private void moveUp(int x, int y, boolean [][] grid){
    if(y==0) return;
    else{
        if (grid[x][y-1]) return;
        grid[x][y-1]=true;
        start(x,y-1,grid);
        grid[x][y-1]=false;
    }
}
   private void moveLeft(int x, int y, boolean [][] grid){
    if(x==0) return;
    else{
        if (grid[x-1][y]) return;
        grid[x-1][y]=true;
        start(x-1,y,grid);
        grid[x-1][y]=false; 
    }
}
private void moveDown(int x, int y, boolean [][] grid){
    if(x==3 && y==3){
        sol++;
        grid[x][y]=true;
        return;
    }
    else if(y==3) return;
    else{
        if (grid[x][y+1]) return;
        grid[x][y+1]=true;
        start(x,y+1,grid);
        grid[x][y+1]=false;
    }
}


private void moveRight(int x, int y, boolean [][] grid){
    if(x==3 && y==3){
        sol++;
        grid[x][y]=true;
        return;
    }else if(x==3) return;
    else{
        if (grid[x+1][y]) return;
        grid[x+1][y]=true;
        start(x+1,y,grid);
        grid[x+1][y]=false; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Few lines of recursion will solve this.

```
    public static int WaysToExit(int x, int y)
    {
        if (x==0 || y == 0)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return (WaysToExit(x - 1, y) + WaysToExit(x , y-1));
        }
    }
```